# How to make the bottom button not click if another button is directly on top of it?

Tags: swift

I have this game where eight buttons appear on the screen. It is inevitable that they will eventually appear on top of each other. However, when you click a button with one underneath it, the button on the bottom clicks instead. I tried to use the zPosition and that makes buttons appear on top of one another, but still it will call the function of the bottom button. Anyone know how I can fix this?

```
button1Label.layer.zPosition = 100
button2Label.layer.zPosition = 99
button3Label.layer.zPosition = 98
button4Label.layer.zPosition = 97
button5Label.layer.zPosition = 96
button6Label.layer.zPosition = 95
button7Label.layer.zPosition = 94
button8Label.layer.zPosition = 93
```

Answer (score 0):

The button that was last added to the parent view (using `addSubview()`) will be the one that receives clicks. To change the order of the buttons, you can re-add them to the parent view (no need to remove them first. Adding will automatically reposition the button.)

Comment: how do I do this